# laravel 4 - count rows of each related table

Tags: laravel-4, count, eloquent, relationship

I want to paginate users and count likes, comments and pictures for each. This is what I do now, but it is slow. (the select pics takes about 80ms on 6000 pics and 30 users)

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('pics', 'comments', 'likes')
                    ->groupBy('users.displayname')
                    ->paginate(30);

    return View::make('usersoverview')->with('users',$users);
}
```

How can I just count the rows? 
(each table has a 'user'/'user_id' with the id of the user in it)

The relationships of Model 'User':

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment','user');
}  

public function pics()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Pic','user_id');
}

public function likes()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Like','user');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using eloquent and getting results, you get them as a `Collection` type, or how other people call it, Arrays on steroids.

If you take a look at the [Collection](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html) class you will see a method called [**count**](http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count) which should do the job.

Comment: okay, that lets me count the results, i think. But I want to reduce the results  and speed the query up. Not get the huge collection, only  3 count-values. Don't know if there is a way to do this.

Comment: @hnes oh, I understand. You just want the row count and not the actual results. I don't know any "built-in" method to do that. In that case, I would recommend the `DB::select()` method. However, you will have to write the query manually.

Answer (score 0):

I have a faster query now. Not perfect, but 8ms - instead of 80ms.

```
    $users = DB::table('users')
                ->select(DB::raw('(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                   FROM pics 
                                   WHERE user_id = users.id) AS countpics,
                                  (SELECT COUNT(*)
                                   FROM comments
                                   WHERE user = users.id) AS countcomments,
                                  (SELECT count(*)
                                   FROM likes
                                   WHERE user = users.id) AS countlikes,
                                  username,
                                  displayname'))
                ->groupBy('username')
                ->paginate(30);
```